# How do I go about creating a submission portal of this nature?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a portal or submission page where people can submit flow chart like information. They will ask an initial question in a form and then subsequently create choices for the initial form box. Those choices can then be linked to further questions and choices to create a flow chart of information. I am very new to programming and have been learning PHP and MySQL. I have completed 4 projects with HTML/CSS alone for just simple static websites. I have attached a picture for a visual representation of what I mean -> [Flowchart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tz2q0.png). It is important that the relationship between the information entered is maintained.

How would I structure a database to place information collected in a such a manner to be able to display it later as choices and information others can work through on the front end.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You could use AJAX to query the DB for additional choices based on the first/subsequent choice(s). You then would update the DOM with new data. This is too broad as is for SO though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple DB table structure to organize your data.

```
tbl_questions (store all questions with it's ID which can be a primary key)
--------------
question_id | question_text 


tbl_options (Store all kind of Options for questions with it's text)
--------------
option_id | option_text 


tbl_question_options (table for map questions ids with corrosponding options ids)
---------------------
question_id | option_id | next_question_id


tbl_user_transaction (Hold all user transaction when answering questions)
----------------------
user_id | question_id | option_id | date_time
```

Hope, it'll help you.